# Difference between PurgeContentAsync and BeginPurgeContentAsync

Tags: azure, asynchronous, azure-cdn

Working with the Azure CDN Management package and have came across several methods for achieving the same results.

- [`PurgeContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.cdn.fluent.endpointsoperationsextensions.purgecontent?view=azuremgmtcdn-fluent-1.0.0) - Synchronous method
- [`PurgeContentAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.cdn.fluent.endpointsoperationsextensions.purgecontentasync?view=azuremgmtcdn-fluent-1.0.0) - Asynchronous method
- [`BeginPurgeContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.cdn.fluent.endpointsoperationsextensions.beginpurgecontent?view=azuremgmtcdn-fluent-1.0.0) - Old async pattern, usually has a corresponding Complete method (however doesn't in this instance)

And finally

- and [`BeginPurgeContentAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.cdn.fluent.endpointsoperationsextensions.beginpurgecontentasync?view=azuremgmtcdn-fluent-1.0.0) - This is the method I'm unsure about. Is it essentially an asynchronous fire and forget method?

`PurgeContentAsync` took over 2 minutes to complete, where as `BeginPurgeContentAsync` took a few seconds.

Is this similar behaviour to purging content from the portal where it is purged in the background?